# add to function without completely overwriting it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have some code that looks like this,

```
const pageDefinitions = require("path/to/files")

pages[SOME_PAGE_URI] = {
    ...pageDefinitions(pages)
    view: 'path/to/view'
};
```

The pageDeinfinitions has a method in called a hooks object called `prerender` I want to add my own code the prerender method, while keeping the original method intact also is this possible?

I have tried,

```
pages[SOME_PAGE_URI].hooks.prerender = (req, res, next) => {
   alert("here");
}
```

But this appears to overwrite the original prerender method, is there away to get the prerender method from `pageDeinfinitions` and load/overload/spread (i'm not sure) it into my own method above?

Comment: Get a reference to the original function and call it in your own? That said: unless your enhancement explicitly plays nice with the existing code this is a potential recipe for disaster. If this is your own code it'd be *much* cleaner to provide a hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try storing a reference to the original pre-render function and calling it in the new one.

```js
const originalPrerender = pages[SOME_PAGE_URI].hooks.prerender;

const newPrerender = (req, res, next) => {
   originalPrerender(req, res, next); // Call the original
   alert("here");
}

pages[SOME_PAGE_URI].hooks.prerender = newPrerender;
```

Comment: I wondered this too, and hopefully it works, but I'm not familiar enough with the `next` callback system of webapp etc. It might be necessary to instead pass in a different `next` function to `originalPrender`.

Comment: @edemaine Then pass a different one in--but are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

Just as you are setting the `prerender` method, you can also *get* it and "back it up" before overwriting it.  Then you can call your backed-up method as well as your own code.

```
let _prerender = pages[SOME_PAGE_URI].hooks.prerender;

pages[SOME_PAGE_URI].hooks.prerender = (req, res, next) => {
    let data = _prerender(req, res, next);

   alert("here");
}
```

Here, `_prerender` is the original method, and you can call it when you override.

---

Depending on how things work with the original method, you may need to instead use:

```
let _prerender = pages[SOME_PAGE_URI].hooks.prerender.bind(pages[SOME_PAGE_URI].hooks);
```

to make sure its `this` value is correct.